# Bandwidth Usage

Tags: bandwidth, phishing

I am not sure if this is the correct forum to be posting to, but I thought someone might be able to help?

I have a client running Zen Garden on their site which was phished not too long ago. Ever since then, his bandwidth usage on the site has hit the roof and I was wondering if anyone know of a solution to this please?

Thanks!

Comment: This is not a forum but a QA site and your question is too much vague

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Maybe reword your question to say something like 'How do I measure the bandwidth on my site? I am using the operating system 'X' and the webserver 'foo', if that's what you want to know.

Answer (score 1):

If the site was compromised, nuke the server and start again. See also:

https://serverfault.com/questions/6159/aftermath-of-hack

https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/intrusion-cleanup

Comment: Also, remember to add in any security patches/processes that are needed to prevent the same thing happening again.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you determine you've been hacked, take your webserver off the network please. Your server may be serving malware, spamming people, functioning as part of a botnet and serving bad stuff for the bad guys.

If you are using Apache webserver, take a look at some of the other [Log modules](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html#other) provided by Apache. These can help you track down if your webserver is doing anything strange. These two sound relevant:

**Logging actual bytes sent and received**

mod_logio adds in two additional LogFormat fields (%I and %O) that log the actual number of bytes received and sent on the network.

**Forensic Logging**

mod_log_forensic provides for forensic logging of client requests. Logging is done before and after processing a request, so the forensic log contains two log lines for each request. The forensic logger is very strict with no customizations. It can be an invaluable debugging and security tool.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to an upstream router look at the traffic that is making up the bandwidth; it could be anything from an open proxy to file sharing site full of illegal content.

Comment: Or run `tcpdmp`, set up SNMP monitoring from another host (using eg. Cacti), etc.